# problem in textField in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a textField with PlaceHolder as"Enter Product Name", when I place cursor then it appears   to be "Enter Product......" in 4.2 iOS simulator where as in lower versions it is working fine.

What could be the reason for this and How Can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that "Enter Product Name" just barely fits in the text field, right ? If so, then the issue might be that starting with iOS 4.0 (IIRC), the default font is now *Helvetica Neue* instead of *Helvetica* which sometimes is few pixels wider.

The fix is simply to remove the "Enter" as it is redundant. The user already knows that this is a text field where he can enter some text, he only needs to know what is meant to be entered and that is merely "Product Name". You can also check the *"Adjust Font Size"* checkbox in the info window of the text field and enter a smaller minimum font size.

Comment: In iOS 4.0,4.1 it is working fine but in iOS 4.2 it is not working

Comment: Does the string "Enter Product Name" on iOS 4.0 have enough space to the right or is it almost touching the side of the text field ? If it is almost touching, then my two suggestions will help.

Answer (score 1):

this problem would be of the textfield size or arc code